# Unable to disable downloading images in headless mode for Selenium Chrome WebDriver using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to disable my driver from loading/downloading images on a website. It should increase speed and also decrease the amount of time it takes to load a site as images wouldn't be downloaded, I still want to be able to find elements and interact with them like sending keys and clicking. The answer located here [How to disable CSS in Python selenium using ChromeOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031428/how-to-disable-css-in-python-selenium-using-chromeoptions)
**DOES** not answer my question as it disables everything. Im unable to interact with elements. This defeats the purpose of selenium as I could just use requests.

Here is all my imports for reference.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Im able to disable images when running a regular driver using the following code.

```
option = Options()
chrome_prefs = {}
option.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
option.add_argument('window-size=1680,941')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option,executable_path='path')
driver.get('https://yahoo.com/')
```

No images are loaded/downloaded when I go to 'yahoo.com' as seen in this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuWyt.jpg

When I use the same code but add the 'headless' line it loads images.

```
option = Options()
chrome_prefs = {}
option.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
option.add_argument('window-size=1680,941')
option.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option,executable_path='path')
driver.get('https://yahoo.com/')
driver.save_screenshot('screen_shot2.png')
```

The driver still loads the images as seen in this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9ca5.jpg
is there any fix out there for this? Thank you!

Comment: can you link where a working answer is? Ive looked through a-lot of solutions and non of them have worked for me

Comment: The answer doesn't work as I can't click on buttons now, before on non headless mode i was still able to click buttons

Comment: headless mode does not have a frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_prefs = {}
option.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
option.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=option)

driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

Code above works for me.

```
option.headless = True        ## this does the trick.
```