# Is there a way to only load needed objects in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

For my project I have to log in a lot, only now I want to speed up that process by only loading what I need. (so no images and CSS and if possible also some divs not)

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if images block is enough:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
# 1 - Allow all images
# 2 - Block all images
# 3 - Block 3rd party images 
profile.set_preference("permissions.default.image", 2)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

For bigger blocking here you have solution from [other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031428/how-to-disable-css-in-python-selenium-using-chromeoptions):

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values': {'cookies': 2, 'images': 2, 'javascript': 2, 
                            'plugins': 2, 'popups': 2, 'geolocation': 2, 
                            'notifications': 2, 'auto_select_certificate': 2, 'fullscreen': 2, 
                            'mouselock': 2, 'mixed_script': 2, 'media_stream': 2, 
                            'media_stream_mic': 2, 'media_stream_camera': 2, 'protocol_handlers': 2, 
                            'ppapi_broker': 2, 'automatic_downloads': 2, 'midi_sysex': 2, 
                            'push_messaging': 2, 'ssl_cert_decisions': 2, 'metro_switch_to_desktop': 2, 
                            'protected_media_identifier': 2, 'app_banner': 2, 'site_engagement': 2, 
                            'durable_storage': 2}}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://play.google.com/store')
```